# What should I do if my answer is the same to different questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Sometimes I have an answer that would fit multiple questions. I don't think that cross-posting the same content is a good idea, so what is supposed to be the best behavior?
Sometimes I give similar answer to all similar questions, other times I just paste a link to my answer in a comment, as I believe that a link only answer is not well accepted, but I feel like none of my solutions are the best.

Comment: This is what flagging as duplicates is for. "Flagging" sounds worse than it is. In the end, the question will be closed with a link to the duplicate question. Think of it as pointing users to one central post with the answer they're looking for. Sounds like you already do this by posting your own link in the comments, but I think flagging goes one step further in helping automate the closing dups process.

Comment: Cross-site FAQ dupe: [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/571958)

Comment: Oh the irony! :p

Comment: Check if the questions are dupe. Likely, they will be. If not, then posting the same twice is okay.

Comment: I've posted the same solution to a very similar problem, and flagged all other similar questions as duplicates.

Comment: How did you choose the canonical question (duplicate target)?

Comment: I chose the first one in chronological order among the four that were more on target